# Indexing in elastic search using NEST

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

I have recently started learning/using elasticsearch and I am trying to index some documents using NEST (c# client) but after I index one document or run a bulk index the read_only_allow_delete is set to true in the index settings. So next call for indexing documents results in 403. If I set this to false again, it is set back to true again after the next call.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

UPDATE:
I found the issue. It was actually the disk space as explained in the documentation when the disk space is over 95% full this flag is automatically set. It is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html)

Comment: did you try this solution https://discuss.elastic.co/t/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api/110282/5

Comment: yes but next time I index a document it is set to true again